# get location for log4j config stored outside application

Tags: java, maven, log4j, datanucleus

We are doing a maven project which is using datanucleus which logs with log4j so can't use logback. Where can I put the log4j config file outside the application so that the different VM environments have access to it. How can I get the location of the config file without hard coding the classpath?

Comment: Any reason you can't define it as a java property (e.g. -Dprop.name=value)?  Then your app just loads the config file based on the property.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the path in log4j.properties.

```
log4j.appender.file.File=path_to_log_file
```

For details, please check this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/).

Comment: Please include the example in your post directly, thank you.